# Azure Api Management Policy 302

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have an Api which provides a 302 redirect to aws s3. I would like to handle this in Apim and just provide the data from the API it redirects to. Has anymore managed to perform this via a policy?

Comment: Can you please guide on how you achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#ForwardRequest for follow-redirects attribute